# how to compare multiple columns with same value in Oracle SQL with OR

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the below query where i am comparing multiple columns with same sub query multiple times.
is there a way to call only one sub query compare with multiple columns.
I know it is possible for ***AND*** but is it possible for ***OR***.

```
select * from catalog 
where 
APPROVER_USER=(select usr_key from usr where usr_login='abcd')
or CERTIFIER_USER =(select usr_key from usr where usr_login='abcd')
or FULFILLMENT_USER =(select usr_key from usr where usr_login='abcd')
;
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong query, updated the sub query.  is it make sense now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be comparing `user_key` in the subquery based on a *specific* user.  There seems to be no need for the `usr` table at all:

```
select c.*
from catalog c
where 437391 in (c.APPROVER_USER, c.CERTIFIER_USER, c.FULFILLMENT_USER);
```

EDIT:

For the revised question, I would just recommend `join`:

```
select c.*
from catalog c join
     users u
     on u.usr_login = ? and
        u.user_key in (c.APPROVER_USER, c.CERTIFIER_USER, c.FULFILLMENT_USER);
```